# Use a phing ForEach loop to execute tasks

Tags: phing

I want to execute an arbitrary selection of tasks in a Phing build.

I'm passing in a list of modules for building.  Each module is of a particular type. The type is specified in the name, as {type}_{unitname}. I started with a build file that took a single module name and built it, that works fine.  I now want to pass in a list of modules and have it build all of them. (What I'd *really* like to do is load the list of modules from an XML manifest file, but perhaps one thing at a time).

I've tried multiple ways and have found a problem with each.

I seem to need an ad-hoc task to derive my properties (task and related directory settings) from the module name.  This seems to cause problems, but not at first.

At first I tried to use the loop variable as the target

```
<foreach list="${mylist}" param="item" target="${item"} />
```

but it doesn't seem to allow a variable as a target name.  So I split it up into two tasks.

```
<foreach list="${parts}" param="dTarg" target="doIt" >
<task name="DoIt">
    <phingcall target="build">
        <property name="extension" value="${dTarg}" />
    </phingcall -->
</task>
```

My problem here is (I think) "extension" is a constant and thus can't be overwritten. I tried using "var", which the docs say is a thing, but my setup complains it doesn't exist. Is it a 3.0 feature?  I'm running 2.17.

So I tried changing the "phingcall" to "phing" and put my main functionality in a separate file.  Here I run into problems with the ad-hoc task again.  If I put it in the "subordinate" file, it complains that's it's re-declared (I think, the message isn't very helpful) when the file is called a second time. If I leave it in the main file, the subordinate file can't find it, even with inheritrefs and inheritall set.

How can I execute tasks whose names are in list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> At first I tried to use the loop variable as the target
>
> <foreach list="${mylist}" param="item" target="${item"} />
>
> but it doesn't seem to allow a variable as a target name

The `target` attribute of the `foreach` task is able to use variables as a value, but at this point `param="item"` is not yet available but in the target it is.

> So I split it up into two tasks.
>
> ```
> <foreach list="${parts}" param="dTarg" target="doIt" >
> <task name="DoIt">
>     <phingcall target="build">
>         <property name="extension" value="${dTarg}" />
>     </phingcall>
> </task>
> ```

Here you try to use a `task` task which is simply not a valid `target`.

What you want to do instead is to have `target`s to iterate over. The following example demonstrates the usage:

#### Input build.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<project name="test" default="main">
    <property name="mylist" value="A,B,C" />

    <target name="main">
        <foreach list="${mylist}" param="item" target="DoIt"/>
    </target>

    <target name="DoIt">
        <echo>${item}</echo>
    </target>

</project>
```

#### Output

```
test > main:


test > DoIt:

     [echo] A

test > DoIt:

     [echo] B

test > DoIt:

     [echo] C

BUILD FINISHED
```

#### Complex Example (with property override and inheritAll)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<project name="test" default="main">
    <property name="mylist" value="A,B,C" />

    <target name="main">
        <foreach list="${mylist}" param="item" target="DoIt"/>
    </target>

    <target name="DoIt">
        <phingcall target="${item}" inheritAll="true">
            <property name="extension" override="true" value="${item}-ext" />
        </phingcall>
    </target>

    <target name="A">
        <echo>Inside target ${item} with ${extension} extension</echo>
    </target>

    <target name="B">
        <echo>Inside target ${item} with ${extension} extension</echo>
    </target>

    <target name="C">
        <echo>Inside target ${item} with ${extension} extension</echo>
    </target>
</project>
```

#### Output

```
test > main:


test > DoIt:


test > A:

     [echo] Inside target A with A-ext extension

test > DoIt:


test > B:

     [echo] Inside target B with B-ext extension

test > DoIt:


test > C:

     [echo] Inside target C with C-ext extension

BUILD FINISHED
```

#### Example execute as one task with changed values from the list

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<project name="test" default="main">
    <property name="mylist" value="A,B,C" />

    <target name="main">
        <foreach list="${mylist}" param="item" target="DoIt"/>
    </target>

    <target name="DoIt">
        <phingcall target="build">
            <property name="extension" override="true" value="${item}-ext" />
        </phingcall>
    </target>

    <target name="build">
        <echo>Inside target build with ${extension}</echo>
    </target>
</project>
```

#### Output

```
test > main:


test > DoIt:


test > build:

     [echo] Inside target build with A-ext

test > DoIt:


test > build:

     [echo] Inside target build with B-ext

test > DoIt:


test > build:

     [echo] Inside target build with C-ext

BUILD FINISHED
```

#### Simplified and final build

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<project name="test" default="main">
    <property name="mylist" value="A,B,C" />

    <target name="main">
        <foreach list="${mylist}" param="item" target="build">
            <property name="extension" override="true" value="${item}-ext" />
        </foreach>
    </target>

    <target name="build">
        <echo>Inside target build with ${extension}</echo>
    </target>
</project>
```

#### Output

```
test > main:


test > build:

     [echo] Inside target build with A-ext

test > build:

     [echo] Inside target build with B-ext

test > build:

     [echo] Inside target build with C-ext

BUILD FINISHED
```